# I'm getting device.uuid undefined in phonegap ios plaform

Tags: ios, cordova, uuid

I'm developing an app in phonegap.
I'm getting device.uuid undefined in ios whereas the same code works perfectly in android.
Help me out.

Comment: It's hard to understand what went wrong. show codes

Comment: Have you used the device plugin of phonegap?

Comment: @SujataChanda yes. I have installed the plugin..

Comment: Weird. I have always used `window.device.uuid` and it worked perfectly.

Comment: @SujataChanda That's what i'm wondering.. working perfectly in android but when i try to alert windwo.device.uuid in ios.. it's null.

Answer (score 0):

i know this question is bit old. but want to answer incase anyone is still searching for the answer. i got the device plugin working in iphone by fetching the value after device ready event

> deviceModel = device.model;  devicePlatform = device.platform; 
>   deviceUUID = device.uuid;  deviceVersion = device.version;